# Android Room database Average query by time in millisec

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Find average of value in every hour using `timeMills`
for eaxample i have 20 value in 1h it add and give me the average of every hour average value using timeMills (use timeMills donot use String time).

I am using this query but found 0 values

```
List<DevicesValuesDB> getAverage();

 @Query("SELECT DATE(timeMills / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS timeMills,\n" +
        "       AVG(value) AS avg\n" +
         "FROM devicesvaluesdb\n" +
        "GROUP BY timeMills")
    List<DevicesValuesDB> gettime();
```

Model

```
  @Entity
public class DevicesValuesDB {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public Integer id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "value")
private Double value;

@ColumnInfo(name = "time")
private String time;

@ColumnInfo(name = "timeMills")
private long timeMills;

}
```

Comment: did you use exactly this field in `DevicesValuesDB` class?

Comment: yes i am using this same

Comment: DevicesValuesDB  is table name

Comment: did you imported correct class in query return list?

Comment: List<DevicesValuesDB> getAverage();

Comment: Columns returned by the query: [timeMills,avg] shows this error

Comment: did you have `id,takenTime,isSync,height,weight,bmi` this fields in Entity class

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error says:

Your query returns `timeMills,avg` and you are storing the result in `List<DevicesValuesDB>` . With `timeMills,avg` Room can't create `DevicesValuesDB` object. So Room expects `[id,takenTime,isSync,height,weight,bmi]` this fields to create a `DevicesValuesDB` object.

I think you have imported wrong class for `List<DevicesValuesDB>` or you didn't post full Class

Comment: I want average values in every hour forexample i have 10 values in 1am and then query return 10 values average, with time i n 1 value and so on

Comment: i think its query issue?

Comment: i want every hour value average

Comment: i am not clear about your requirements, for query simplicity you can query between 2 time and make average with `total sum/ number of rows`

Comment: yes i search this on google, but i want average of value from every hour

Comment: means you have 10 values in 1am then it return 1 value(average) in 1am and so on other hours

Comment: i want average of value in every hour

Comment: i want average of (value) in every hour